# SelectedIndex is not changing SharePoint asp DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am writing a SharePoint App and have a problem with drop down list. Its SelectedIndex is not changing. I read many questions and answers and they suggest using `IsPostBack` or `EnableViewState` to `true`. I did both with no success.

ASP code:

```
<div class="value">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="groupingDropDownList" runat="server" EnableViewState="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="groupingDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
</div>
```

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {                
                groupingDropDownList.DataSource = sourceList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x });
                groupingDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
                groupingDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
                groupingDropDownList.DataBind();
            }
}
```

Event `SelectedIndexChanged` is not firing because index is not changing. I set a breakpoint on line `if (!Page.IsPostBack)` and it is always 0.

Comment: How could it change since it's just loading in its initial state?

Comment: @IrishChieftain What do you mean it's loading in initial state? Or rather which part of the code does it and how could I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know what was my mistake, it was the line:

```
groupingDropDownList.DataSource = sourceList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x });
```

I always set value equal to class name and since the value didn't change, the control didn't notice index change.

Answer (score 0):

In the !Page.IsPostBack block you are populating your dropdown for the first time. You seem to be trying to detect a change in the dropdown selection as it is loading - which is impossible.

So, to test it you should do a check in the postback of the page or in the groupingDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event handler.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{                
    groupingDropDownList.DataSource 
        = sourceList.Select(x => new { x.Name, Value = x });
    groupingDropDownList.DataTextField = "Name";
    groupingDropDownList.DataValueField = "Value";
    groupingDropDownList.DataBind();
}
// Actual postback
else
{
    var test = groupingDropDownList.SelectedValue;
}
```

Comment: Still no change

Comment: SharePoint is really tricky. Presumably you're creating this as a Feature and deploying it as a Solution Package? Be sure to uninstall the previous version and reset IIS before deploying and activating your newest version. Other than that I can't help because of limited info on your situation ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes, I heard about this version issue. In my case it was less SharePoint and more C# because I set the same value to each item and the real value didn't change (even though I thought so)